# ogr2ogr large gdb file to SQLite warning: "organizePolygons() received a polygon with more than 100 parts"

Tags: ogr2ogr, geopandas, shapely, spatialite, sqlite

I'm trying to write a .gdb file (could also be any other format, geojson, gpkg, etc.) to a Spatialite DB but it takes awhile and I am getting a warning.

Command:

```
ogr2ogr --config OGR_SQLITE_CACHE 1024 -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -nlt MULTIPOLYGON slite.db tmp_dls/data_d4e815db1/Universe.gdb -nln paqrcel_lines lotlines -gt unlimited
```

Warning message:

```
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received a polygon with more than 100 parts. The processing may be really slow.  You can skip the processing by setting METHOD=SKIP, or only make it analyze counter-clock wise parts by setting METHOD=ONLY_CCW if you can assume that the outline of holes is counter-clock wise defined
```

I know SQLite has low default settings for transactions and memory which is why I added the `-gt unlimited` and `--config OGR_SQLITE_CACHE 1024` options but they dont have any affect on the speed of the command. With those 2 options removed it takes the same amount of time.

Is there a command in ogr2ogr I can use to make this run faster, or should I switch to geopandas and use some shapely function to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The error means that your source data contains a polygon with more than 100 parts. I believe that in this context parts mean rings, both outer and inner ones. Rather good explanation can be found from https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRGeometryFactory.html#a9ce97d39ca2e0dd88f415227e71b7fd5

> Organize polygons based on geometries.  Analyse a set of rings (passed
> as simple polygons), and based on a geometric analysis convert them
> into a polygon with inner rings, (or a MultiPolygon if dealing with
> more than one polygon) that follow the OGC Simple Feature
> specification. All the input geometries must be
> OGRPolygon/OGRCurvePolygon with only a valid exterior ring (at least 4
> points) and no interior rings. The passed in geometries become the
> responsibility of the method, but the papoPolygons "pointer array"
> remains owned by the caller. For faster computation, a polygon is
> considered to be inside another one if a single point of its external
> ring is included into the other one. (unless
> 'OGR_DEBUG_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS' configuration option is set to TRUE. In
> that case, a slower algorithm that tests exact topological
> relationships is used if GEOS is available.) In cases where a big
> number of polygons is passed to this function, the default processing
> may be really slow. You can skip the processing by adding METHOD=SKIP
> to the option list (the result of the function will be a multi-polygon
> with all polygons as toplevel polygons) or only make it analyze
> counterclockwise polygons by adding METHOD=ONLY_CCW to the option list
> if you can assume that the outline of holes is counterclockwise
> defined (this is the convention for example in shapefiles, Personal
> Geodatabases or File Geodatabases). For FileGDB, in most cases, but
> not always, a faster method than ONLY_CCW can be used. It is
> CCW_INNER_JUST_AFTER_CW_OUTER. When using it, inner rings are assumed
> to be counterclockwise oriented, and following immediately the outer
> ring (clockwise oriented) that they belong to. If that assumption is
> not met, an inner ring could be attached to the wrong outer ring, so
> this method must be used with care. If the OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS
> configuration option is defined, its value will override the value of
> the METHOD option of papszOptions (useful to modify the behavior of
> the shapefile driver)

I am not sure if I understood right how to control which method is used for analysing the rings but I would try with this command:

```
ogr2ogr --config OGR_SQLITE_CACHE 1024 -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -nlt MULTIPOLYGON slite.db tmp_dls/data_d4e815db1/Universe.gdb -nln paqrcel_lines lotlines -gt unlimited --config OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS CCW_INNER_JUST_AFTER_CW_OUTER
```

Write a mail to gdal-dev list if this command does not make any difference or throws some error.

Comment: Unfortunately I still received the same error and the command still took awhile to complete (a little over a minute). I'll send my question over to the mailing list, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Before that check if you really have such complex polygons in your data and if possible, isolate the geometry. You can also debug a bit by deleting the most complex polygons and testing if the conversion is faster without them.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server as a destination (`-f "MSSQLSpatial"`), adding the following switch to the command line made the message go away, and indeed seemed to speed up the load process.

`--config OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS SKIP`

So, in my case the full command was:

`ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=SERVER;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=yes;" "C:\PATH\FILENAME.gdb\a0000000a.gdbtable"  -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt -overwrite -progress -skipfailures --config OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS SKIP`