# Importing a .gdb file into PostGIS using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I am trying to import data in `.gdb` format using the OSGEO4W console:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=XX.X.X.X \
    port=5432 \
    dbname=XXgeodados \
    user=XXXXXX \
    password=XXXX" \
    XXXXX.gdb \
    -lco SCHEMA=XXX \
    --config PG_USE_COPY YES \
    -overwrite
```

However, the following error message always appears:

```
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received a polygon with more than 100 parts. 
The processing may be really slow. You can skip the processing by setting
METHOD=SKIP, or only make it analyze counter-clock wise parts by setting 
METHOD=ONLY_CCW if you can assume that the outline of holes is
counter-clock wise defined
```

I did not understand how exactly you would use `METHOD=SKIP` or `METHOD=ONLY_CCW`

Could it be a topology problem?
Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It is not an error but just a warning. The process should continue and finish if you have time to wait. But you can also have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370739/ogr2ogr-large-gdb-file-to-sqlite-warning-organizepolygons-received-a-polygon and add this into your command `--config OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS SKIP`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Warning message

The warning message says that the processing can be slow. **Don't worry about it.** It is just a warning.

It does make sense for huge datasets, but for smaller ones, you don't notice any slowness.

#### Avoiding the message

If you want to get rid of this warning, you can set the variable `OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS=SKIP`.

You can use it like this:

```
OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS=SKIP ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5433 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx" Trilhos.gdb -lco SCHEMA=poligonos -lco OVERWRITE=YES Concelhos
```

Other options are available, like `OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS=ONLY_CCW`. Check the [GDAL api](https://gdal.org/api/ogrgeometry_cpp.html#_CPPv4N18OGRGeometryFactory16organizePolygonsEPP11OGRGeometryiPiPPKc) for more details about these options.